# Can't remove screen protector from Macbook Air (2017)

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a screen protector on (I installed it, no one touches my laptop apart from me). It was a no bubble perfect fit on day one. But now I realise (after 7 months) that perfect fit was the greatest trouble for me. I can't even find its edge. Tried hairdryer, nails, scissors, tape, everything that was on the web. Couldn't even lift it slightly. It is adhesse and perfectly fit. I am also afraid I might pull of polarizer if I pull it up (if I could, doesn't seem possible right now) because it is so tightly fit.

Please suggest something.

Comment: Have you a friend that is a surgeon? Those are the skills and tools you may need. Who make the screen protector - knowing the materials might help someone suggest a plan of attack based on adhesives and thickness. You are correct that there is a high chance of physical damage that would be hundreds of dollars to repair without escalating past the tools you’ve already employed.

Comment: @bmike that didn't help

Comment: Sorry, I’ve seen these go badly and I’ve seen these go well. Best wishes you succeed.

Comment: @bmike thanks but you should keep quiet if you couldn't help or something.

Comment: He's telling you the truth and trying to help you.  Have you searched this site for similar issues and seen the results?  It's a very tricky thing to do, as you have seen.  Also, on a community site where you're asking for help, telling someone to keep quiet is counterproductive and can result in nobody helping you.

Comment: @fsb No he's not helping at all. I have no problem with your reply. You also didn't help. But you didn't talk rubbish either. I don't have problem with replies. I have problem with replies that increase frustration of a person in trouble rather than improving it.

Comment: bmike has always been helpful to me, and to thousands of others, for many years. I think that little blue diamond is significant, too - you should look into that.

Comment: @IconDaemon Bro, I'm a common man. I don't care about fancy blue or red diamonds. If something is worth liking, I'd like it. If it is not helping at all, even then I won't bother to say anything but if it is worsening the situation, I'd speak against it rather than curbing my words just for the sake of some fancy looking blue diamond.